# Vegetable oil to oil a bike?

Tags: frugal, lubricant

Is vegetable oil as good as motor oil to oil a bike?

Comment: Why? HHH has many ideas on removing the chain, immersing it in parafin, and then reattaching the chain.

Comment: Seriously, just go to your bike shop, get some lube, and put a drop on each link.

Comment: Yes, you should immerse your bike in canola oil weekly.

Comment: @wdypdx22 - Then coat with egg, dip in bread crumbs, bake in a 350 degree oven for 20 minutes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best chain lubricant for road bikes?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3/best-chain-lubricant-for-road-bikes)

Comment: @ChrisW - I'm on the fence about whether this is a duplicate or not. On the one hand, it covers a lot of the same ground as the earlier question. However, this is [a good variation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/) of the earlier question, and I kinda like having a variation on it specifically asking if cooking oil will do the job.

Comment: I understand that *part* of the problem behind using cooking oil is that it goes bad and can smell faintly like, well, rotting food. Why does cooking oil do this and not chain lube?

Comment: @Neil Chain oils are "[mineral oils](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil)", aren't they? My guess is that, if they're made from petroleum, any long/complicated organic/vegetable fats which can go rancid already decomposed/disappeared millions of years ago, and they're distilled.

Comment: @ChrisW - Not certain. A shame there's no [Chemistry.SE yet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89418/149375).

Comment: At high speed, an expensive, virgin, olive oil can make your bicycle smell much better for the following traffic.

Comment: @Neil Fein: @ChrisW: it is not duplicate, my earlier question about substitutes for chain oils generally contained this question. I think this question is unsolved so it requires this type of focussed question. My other question found out that chain oils work through a number of mechanism. One is creating electron turbulences by having some very e-negative substances but there are other mechanisms. I find newbies ridiculing this topic spam -- I hope mods would hinder such actions, there are still chemical challenges. I have tried to outline things, still investigating.

Comment: @hhh - Nobody's proposing closing this, no need to worry. Also, rather than call somebody's comments [spam](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spam) (a term I personally find insulting, I think you mean "clutter"?), if you want to continue discussing something, you might consider opening a thread in meta if you think a discussion in the comments is getting overlong.

Comment: @Neil Fein: the word "Spam" here refers to the observation that some sort of data is unrelated and won't help to answer a question -- precisely according to the original meaning of the Monty Python -- it is not offensive, it is constructive. Please, remove the pejorative comments about "smell". The question is still **unsolved** -- if no-one is going to remove the ridiculing comments, I doubt whether this question will attract professionals. Keep it clean with **related information**. Look how people are repeating themselves, we need to remove the clutter -- and focus on the unsolved chemistry

Comment: When cooking oil goes bad, it smells bad. This is a reason to avoid using it, and is not unrelated.

Comment: @Neil Fein: pardon ... did you read this comment `"At high speed, an expensive, virgin, olive oil can make your bicycle smell much better for the following traffic."`? What the heck has the high-speed, expensive or virgin to do with this question? -Nothing! It is spam, totally unrelated information --apparently meant to be humorous -- but it distracts the attention from the chemical problems. I stress that the question is still **unsolved**, please, keep it clean without marketing/social clutter. The problems are scientific.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were referring to a commet elsewhere (I think it was on another thread). About the comment you mention, there's no need to remove it. Comments are meant for exactly what they're being used for -- [commenting](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/comment). It's *answers* that need to stay focused. Again, take this to meta or Meta.SO if you want to continue.

Comment: I wanted to know because I have no lube in the house and my chain is squeaking. I want to ride my Fuji Newest tomorrow without the "ch(a)in music", so I'd like to use a tiny bit of vegetable oil just this once to take the squeak out of the equation for a couple hours. Nothing *bad* will happen if I do this, right?

Comment: I think it's OK as an "emergency" chain oil.  You should probably remove as much as possible and replace with something else as soon as you can, but it would be OK for a week or two (though maybe not the optimum lubricant).

Comment: I'm a bit annoyed by the answers here. They are mostly-nonanswers and saying to go get cheap oil. The thing is I can't go to the store, I just want to know if this will be an acceptable temporary solution to see if the bike even works decently. I think user652 is correct.

Answer (score 33):

Vegetable oils tend to "polymerize", that is become sticky and solid.  Castor oil, for instance, is an excellent lubricant that was favored for racing autos and motorcycles for a long time.  The reason it never became popular for regular cars was that it also built up a lot of sticky, cruddy goo.   Racing engines are regularly torn down and rebuilt; no matter.
Not so your sedan.
The oils used in oil-based paints are usually vegetable-based as well; they tend to become quite solid after a while.

As I've noted before, lubes, especially chain lubes, seem to be a "thing" for serious cyclists.  Chain lube threads on dedicated bike forums tend to go on and on and on...
It's the engineering mentality at work.  "Maybe I can get 100 more miles out of my chain if I concoct my own special blend!"   Maybe...
Chain lubes are cheap.  They cost at most what, 10 bucks for a bottle sufficient for a year?
As well, chains are cheap.  Oh, you can spend a lot for super-deluxe items, but a good, well-made standard chain is under 20 bucks and will last most riders as long as they keep the bike if lubed and cleaned properly.

**Related**

- ["Best chain lubricant for road bikes?"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3/best-chain-lubricant-for-road-bikes) Asks about the best lubricant out of conventional oils and lubricants
- ["Substitutes for chain lubricants"](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2703/are-there-substitutes-for-chain-lubricant) Asks about non-traditional substitutes for chain lubricant

Comment: Just to add an anecdote. Castor oil was used in open cockpit WWI era aircraft. Caster oil also has strong laxative effect.  An unfortunate combination !

Comment: "Vegetable oils tend to "polymerize", that is become sticky and solid" -- I'm pretty sure that this is why I "season" my cast iron cookware in order to make it non-stick. And..." Chain lubes are cheap. They cost at most what, 10 bucks for a bottle sufficient for a year? As well, chains are cheap." I wish I could upvote your answer more than once!

Comment: Also, I don't see the point in removing a chain, soaking in paraffin, etc... I love your answer M. Werner

Comment: @wdypdx22 it's the only way to remove all the old oil and clean it without using water containing detergents.

Comment: "Chain lube threads on dedicated bike forums tend to go on and on and on... It's the engineering mentality at work." -- This is my favorite quote!

Answer (score 9):

On the chain, not so much. As M. Werner says, it polymerises and turns into stick goo fairly quickly, and there's nothing you can do to stop that. So you can really only put it somewhere that it's easy to remove. Like a chain. Then you just need to use a chain cleaner on it every couple of weeks and reapply the oil. Using vege oil other places could be awful. Inside a hub gear especially, for one example.

I have one friend who tried vegetable oil on his chain, and experimented with a variety of oils. He doesn't use vege oil any more, from memory because it turned to black goo too fast. I believe that even cheap motor oil is better. I have emailed him a link, hopefully he will chime in.

Edit: he says he doesn't have anything useful to add.

Answer (score 8):

[Mineral oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mineral_oil) consists of "alkanes" which have a simple chemical formula (C<sub>*n*</sub>H<sub>*2n+2*</sub>).

Fats go [rancid](http://www.meta-synthesis.com/webbook/14_radical/radical.html) because their molecules include relatively complicated/weak bonds.

(I'm less sure about waxes; but oil is more common, in chain lube, than wax).

I've just Googled the oil which my LBS sold me and note that [it says](http://www.finishlineusa.com/products/cross-country-lube.htm), "Finish Line’s WET Lubricant features an Inherently Biodegradable formulation which that between 20% and 60% of the product’s base oils will degrade within 28 days."

Contrast that with [another type of oil](http://www.chainl.com/FAQ.html), which lasts a long time by being mineral oil.

Comment: Just as an addition, I maintain our department's fleet of 25 patrol bikes, and I've been using the Finish Line products for many years now with excellent results.

Answer (score 4):

No.

It's about $5 for a [bottle of chain lube](http://www.jensonusa.com/store/product/CM306B01-Progold+Prolink+Chain+Squeeze+Bottle.aspx?sc=FRGL) and $10 for [a tube of grease](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WYANAG). Those are top-of-the-line lubricants and will last you for months of frequent application. There is absolutely zero reason why you should jeopardize the lifespan of your bicycle by coating it with food.

Comment: You are so right! I just cannot understand why folks want to de-link, remove the chain, melt paraffin, soak the chain in paraffin, and then reassemble the chain. Or, why using vegetable oil would be a good idea at all? Finally, a voice of rationality!

Comment: @wdypdx22: removing-the-chain is essential with unmaintained-or-heavy-used-or-bad-weathered-conditioned(such as winter) chains, you need to get the dirt from inside -- it lowers the friction.

Comment: @wdypdx22: if you read the answer in my link [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2925/wiping-extra-lube-really-important-with-all-types-of-lubes), you could find the reason explained by freiheit: ´"and dirt inside will grind away at the internal parts and wear out the chain faster."´ Now, behave yourself. Stop exaggerating the frugal -chracteristic and try to answer the question. My answer is chemical per se -- why are you attacking me with these bombastic repetitive comments? Totally unrelated, baseless. It distracts attention from the chemical investigation.

Comment: @hhh - Sorry to be bombastic and for the misbehavior.

Comment: @hhh - Really sorry to be bombastic. I

Comment: @wdypdx22: no problem, just forget and let's clean this writing. I hope that you won't see me as a extremist stingy user. When I make frugal questions, I try to simplify things in a way -- it is time-consuming but it does result in creative solutions time-to-time, sometimes to unsolved scientific stuff that I like to look at and particularly interested to research further.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure what the intent behind the question is here, but I have tried vegetable oil, and it's not great. It doesn't smell enough to concern you, but it gets gummy pretty quickly, and picks up dirt. It might be alright if you cleaned and re-applied really regularly (like every 3-4 days?), but I was too lazy to bother.

The reasons I wanted to try vege oil were basically environmental, and because I don't want to use products produced by the petroleum industry. Ok, and perhaps a little symbolism.

Anyway, a quick web search for "environmental bike lubricant" reveals http://www.green-oil.net/environment.html, which looks promising (long-chain polymers extracted from plant oil), and seems to have decent reviews. I haven't tried it yet, but will see if I can get some and try it out.

Answer (score 3):

If your bike was a garage sale or dumpster find, sure, put vegetable oil on it. I do it to old kids' bikes. It works ok, and doesn't get them as greasy as motor oil or axle grease. I've seen a lawn mower that someone filled with canola oil instead of motor oil, and it ran just fine for a long time, though the oil did thicken up and stink.

FWIW there is a vegetable oil based chainsaw bar oil on the market, and I've used cheap corn oil with a little used motor oil as a bar oil for months. It works great, but smokes a little, and has to be drained from the reservoir or it will congeal some.

Some chains aren't cheap. The new "9 speed" chains are $20+, the "10 speed" chains are around $30-80, and the sure to be next 11, 12, 13 speed chains are italian top shelf stuff and $$$$$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question never actually specified which part of the bike was to be oiled, I'll point out that linseed oil (specifically boiled linseed oil) is often used as spoke prep.

In this case, it's used to lubricate the spoke threads during wheel assembly, and the fact that it dries afterwards is desirable as it acts like a threadlock to resist the nipple unscrewing.

Answer (score 0):

Tri-flow now makes a soy-based chain lube:
http://www.triflowlubricants.com/Tri-Flow_Superior_Soy_Lubricant_Drip.html
A big ol' jug of soybean oil from the grocery store has the problems noted elsewhere.

Answer (score -1):

I use Green Oil chain lube and it works just as well as dry lube/petrochemical oil/gt85 ever did. It smells much better too, like some kinda cooking oil.

http://www.green-oil.net/environment.html